# Losing accuracy with double plus

Tags: java

I have a simple code here, however it has not any division or complicated multiplying.

```
for ( double i=.1; i<=1; i+=.1) {
      System.out.println(i);
}
```

But in some cases value of `i` is not accurate, e.g. `.79999999` or `.600000001`.

Why did this happen? How can I change this code that becomes accurate?

Comment: Because floating-point numbers are not exact.

Comment: Possibly the most answer question in programming.  In short you must round the result or use integer arithmetic.  Try `printf("%.1f%n", i)` instead.  Note: `i <= 1` is ideal either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point numbers aren't represented exactly, they lose precision. Try

```
for ( int i=1; i<=10; i+=1) {
      System.out.println("%.f", (double)i/10);
}
```

Comment: This outputs "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1" - you need to add a cast to float or double.

Answer (score 2):

`double` is imprecise - it is designed to hold finite accuracy.

For precise "doubles", use `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(".1");
for ( BigDecimal i= d; ! i.equals(BigDecimal.ONE) ; i = i.add(d) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `int` inside your loop will fix the problem:

```
for (int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    System.out.println(i*0.1);
}
```

This is happening because decimal fractions might lose precision, they're not represented exactly. 
You might want to to know [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more information.

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know what I did wrong. We all want to learn from our mistakes.

Comment: The link may theoretically answer the question, but [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Juhana The link provides the answer. No need to copy paste parts from it IMHO. Reading it will answer OP question. I don't think this is a good reason for downvoting.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I do.  Links are great for pointing to supplementary info or evidence...but for a number of reasons, the post should be able to stand on its own without them.  If it can't, it's at best a half-answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known property of `double`.
 Doubles store numbers in the format of 0.x * 2^y (or 1.x * 2^x). 
This means not all integers are representable exactly, and, most importantly, 
**not all decimal fractions can be represented exactly**.

I'm guessing you should be using something like `BigDecimal` here.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of floating-point-operations. If you want exact value, there are special classes like `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (double i = .1; i <= 1; i += .1) {
    System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(i).setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
}
```